# How to disable Package Manager Console verbosity

Tags: nuget

My nuget package manager console is displaying a lot of detailed log information about what NPM is doing. I'm sure there is a switch somewhere than was turned on, where can i find this switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type in NPM Console: nuget Config -Set Verbosity=normal